# cron not executing python3

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, cron

I am running Raspbian Stretch and have a python 3 script that executes correctly when I am in the relevant directory and input it in the command line as:

```
sudo python3 Example.py
```

The shebang #! line is in the script as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

And made the script executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x Example.py
```

I've tried several variation of below within crontab -e to no avail

10 * * * * python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Example.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As is typical with crontab issues. The environment is not the same as your user or even a sudo/root shell , and `env python3` may not return anything (env simply searches through

Instead you should explicitly use the full path of python which can be found either as `which python3` or `which $(env python3)`  and use that full path in your crontab (typically `/usr/bin/python3` but it is also valid to use one installed elsewhere , e.g. a virtualenv directory)

If your script or program relies on being in the same directory, make sure to change directory

`cd /path/to/dir && /usr/bin/python3 ./Example.py`

Comment: Note shebangs are ignored when called script is called  explicitly as argument to python

Comment: The script should also `cd <relevant directory>`.

Comment: @Ingo this is not strictly necessary unless `Example.py` uses relative paths to CWD in it's logic,  using the full path of the script is also acceptable in many instances. I will edit for completeness

Comment: Maybe, but I have seen many python scripts that cannot find its custom modules if not executed from its current directory.

Comment: Is there a downside in just including the change directory when adding a .py in crontab? (for future reference on best practices)

Comment: @DanBRaelin  In the general, no downside in doing so. in some cases if you have complex environment needs, a helper/caller shell script may be useful, be sure to call such a script with the right shell as `crontab` by default uses `sh`, i.e. `bash -c './myhelper'`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in crontab:

sudo python3 /home/pi/Example.py

You need the full path to Example.py

You don't really need the shebang.

Or sudo crontab -e  for the root crontab with:

python3 /home/pi/Example.py

Comment: The script should also `cd <relevant directory>`.